# Sevenzip extractFile(String file, Stream stream) method stream parameter. c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, 7zip

I am trying to access a file in a .7z file. I know the name of the file in the zip folder and that it exists in the .7z file. Previously I've used the ExtractArchive(templocation) which just dumps all the files into a temporary location. Now I want to be able to grab a specific file without extracting the whole .7z file.

7Zip has a class called the SevenZipExtractor that has a method ExtractFile. I would think that is what I am looking for, but I can't find any decent documentation on it.

What I need clarification on is how to go about getting the Stream parameter passed in correctly.
I am using code like this;

```
//this grabs the zip file and creates a FileInfo array that hold the .7z file (assume there is only one) 
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(ApplicationPath);
FileInfo[] zipFile = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.7z");
//This creates the zipextractor on the zip file I just placed in the zipFile FileInfo array
using (SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor zipExtractor = new SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor(zipFile[0].FullName)) 
//Here I should be able to use the ExtractFile method, however I don't understand the stream parameter, and I can't find any good documentation on the method itself. What is this method looking for?
{
    zipExtractor.ExtractFile("ConfigurationStore.xml", Stream stream);
}
```

Comment: Is that the only version of that method available?  There are no overloads that would take a destination path (`String`)?  I ask because if not, you'll probably have to setup a `FileStream` or something similar for it to write to.  An overload would just be taking your path string and setting it up for you, anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a `FileStream` that SevenZip can write out to:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(ApplicationPath);
FileInfo[] zipFile = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.7z");
using (SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor zipExtractor = new SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor(zipFile[0].FullName)) 
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("", FileMode.Create))  //replace empty string with desired destination
    {
        zipExtractor.ExtractFile("ConfigurationStore.xml", fs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I was looking straight at the Stream class on msdn! The Filestream is much less amorphous and obviously makes more sense! Thanks so much!